# Hide all li tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, html-lists

Please help me to complete my code.
I want to hide all `<li>` tags on body onload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li > ul').hide();    
});
```

Please give me the right variant for the code!

Answer (score 5):

It's `ul > li`, not `li > ul`

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('ul > li').hide(); });
```

Comment: You could just do $('li').hide() as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
  $('li').hide()
})
```

This will search and hide every `<li>` tag on the page. It is better to narrow down the search to improve performance Ex: `$('#mydiv li')` where `mydiv` is the id of the ul tag `<ul id="mydiv">`.